# Xscreensaver on startup, i3wm

Tags: x11, session, i3, xscreensaver

How do I set up xscreensaver to run in the background on login?
Will a simple `xscreensaver &` do the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if I understand it you want to put xscreensaver after starting i3wm ? if you enter into the i3wm config file as the last line `exec xscreensaver`

Comment: Yeah, but should I add the '&' as well?

Comment: I do not think there is need of & , try anyway

Answer (score 2):

Yes, usually just

```
xscreensaver &
```

will do what you want.  But it depends on what else you have in your `.xinitrc` (or `.xsession`) file.  For both of those, you need to leave some program running in the foreground to prevent the script from completing (and stopping X).

If you have a workable script, when adding your command *before* that final program should work.

Further reading:

- [How do xsession, xinitrc and .i3/config play together?](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/18/how-do-xsession-xinitrc-and-i3config-play-together.1.html)
- [e X Window User HOWTO: 3. Running X](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XWindow-User-HOWTO/runningx.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding `exec --no-startup-id xscreensaver` line to your i3wm config file (default `~/.i3/config`) should do.

Appending `&` is not necessary since i3wm doesn't block on the `exec` commands.